# Strange Loading in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am trying to load a URLRequest in UIWebview.

I have tried with several URL. All are working fine.
But in One URL it is behaving strangely.
When I navigated to my webview It took lot of time to load this particular URL.

```
[self.mediaWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://www.whatmakesahighperformanceorganization.com" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]]]];
```

And also It notifies me Loading and Finished loading multiple times.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad...");
    [self.loadingActivityView setHidden:NO];
    [self.loadingActivityView startAnimating];
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad...");
    [self.loadingActivityView stopAnimating];
}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
     NSLog(@"Error=%@",error);
}
```

This is the output I recieved on a single call

```
2012-06-19 15:25:54.255 MyApp[1957:707] webViewDidStartLoad...
2012-06-19 15:25:55.842 MyApp[1957:707] webViewDidStartLoad...
2012-06-19 15:25:55.893 MyApp[1957:707] webViewDidStartLoad...
2012-06-19 15:25:56.675 MyApp[1957:707] webViewDidFinishLoad…
2012-06-19 15:27:03.148 MyApp[1957:707] webViewDidStartLoad...
2012-06-19 15:27:09.336 MyApp[1957:707] webViewDidFinishLoad…
2012-06-19 15:27:52.661 MyApp[1957:707] webViewDidFinishLoad...
2012-06-19 15:27:52.683 MyApp[1957:707] webViewDidFinishLoad…
```

Check the time between 4th and 5th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading this URL in Chrome with the Developer Tools’ Network panel, you can see that it needs 124 requests and transfers 2.96Mb. No wonder it takes ages!

Answer (score 0):

that URL may have many flash content. show that it will take long time.

this url take some timing in the browser also.